# Use of laser in Newton's ring experiment

Tags: interference

In the lab, we perform Newton's Ring experiment with the help of Sodium-Vapour lamp. Why can't we perform the same experiment with LASER ? Please explain the difference in two cases.

Comment: why not? I used a He-Ne laser to obtain some nice photos for my lectures. They are completely useful for a lab experiment. I use the laser as a source in a binocular microscope setup.

Comment: So is it as per our convenience which type (laser or sodium vapour lamp) to choose ?

Comment: Maybe, I do not know any drawback.

Answer (score 1):

Y0u can perform the experiment with a laser but to get a reasonable number of easily visible fringes you would need to increase the width of laser beam with a [beam expander](http://assets.newport.com/webdocuments-en/images/how_to_build_a_beam_expander_5.pdf) although a single lens could be used.

You will note that in the usual arrangement of Newton's rings using a conventional light source, the source is a extended and not a point eg a sodium lamp often with a piece of ground glass between the lamp and the lens/plane arrangement.
This is so as to illuminate as much of the lens/plate arrangement as possible.

Using a laser alone only a small region is illuminated and so few (part) fringes are seen whereas using a beam expander will result in an easily visible set of complete circles.